# Calling Method to Compare Two Strings | Java

Tags: java, string, methods, compare, user-input

I've two classes, StringCompare and StringCompareTest.

StringCompare creates 2 strings that will be assigned by user input in StringCompareTest and has a method to compare the strings.

In StringCompareTest, it won't call the methods - "non-static method compareStrings() cannot be referenced from a static context"

Can anyone help me to call the method and allow my program to run?

Thank you in advance.

```
public class StringCompare {

    // Create two strings 
    String s1 = "";
    String s2 = "";

    // Create method to compare them, to be called in StringCompareTest
    void compareStrings() {
        if (s1.equals(s2)) {
            System.out.println("The strings are equal!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The strings are not equal!");
        }
    }


}
```

`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringCompareTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    StringCompare stringCompare = new StringCompare ();

    // Create Scanner object to get input
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Get strings from user & assign values to strings
    System.out.println("Enter your first string: ");
    String s1 = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter your second string: ");
    String s2 = keyboard.nextLine();

    // Call compareStrings
    compareStrings();

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Try this:

public static void main(String[] args) {

...
StringCompare compare = new StringCompare();
compare.compareStrings(s1,s2);

}

public void compareStrings(String s1, String s2) {


        if (s1.equals(s2)) {
            System.out.println("The strings are equal!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The strings are not equal!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either make the compareString's method static, in which case you should pass the two String's as parameters...

```
public static void compareStrings(s1, s2)
```

...or create an instance of StringCompare, set the values of s1 and s2, and call the method of the instance

```
StringCompare sc = new StringCompare();
sc.s1 = string1;
sc.s2 = string2;
sc.compareString()
```

Either way, I don't see any need to have StringCompareTest extend StringCompare.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a non-static method `compareStrings()`, from a static method (`main(String[])`). This cannot be done because the caller is not associated with an instance of the class, while the method being called is!

That is, you need to create an instance of `StringCompare` and then call the method. E.g.,

```
StringCompare scmp = new StringCompare(s1, s2);
StringCompare.compareStrings();
```

Note that in your code, the variables s1 and s2 in the `main` method are not the same in the `StringCompare` class. You need to make a constructor that takes two string arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can't calling a non-static method and access non-static instance variable into a static method.If you want want access these in you static method means in `static void main()` method you should do it by two ways

**Way-1**

Declare instance variables s1 and s2 as static and also method `void compareStrings()` as static in class `StringCompare`.

```
static String s1 = "";
static String s2 = "";

static void compareStrings() {
        if (s1.equals(s2)) {
            System.out.println("The strings are equal!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The strings are not equal!");
        }
    }
```

**Way-2**

Calling the method `void compareStrings()` into `StringCompareTest` class with creating a object of `StringCompare` class.

```
StringCompare sc = new StringCompare();   
sc.compareStrings();
```